# Wordpress White Screen - WSoD

Tags: wordpress

I have big problem with white screen in wordpress.

I would like to migrate site from live to localhost, **I don't have credentials for hosting**, and I've migrated site using **All In One WP Migration Plugin**.

**Steps:**

1. I've extracted **.wpress** file using **wpress-extractor**.
2. On Localhost installed fresh Wordpress
3. Created new database and imported database from live site
4. Files from extracted **.wpress** file I've copied into **wp-content**
5. Inside wp-config.php change database, set credentials for login, change prefix of database etc ...
6. After thar I've run **Interconnect/it** script to change paths inside Database
7. Finally when I visite site I've got **white screen** , If I try to login I've got login inputs, but when click on submit button I see white screen.

**What I tried:**

1. Deleting all plugins
2. Deleting theme
3. define( 'WP_DEBUG', true )
4. define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
5. Tried to run in incognito mode of Chrome
6. Deleted .htaccess

and still same problem ...
Can someone help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: check server error log

Comment: @kevinniel this is on localhost and error are displaying on web page, but there is no error. On server error will be stored into debug.log file into directory.
This is problem with database I think.

Answer (score 0):

Step1 : First install fresh wordpress in localhost
Step2:  Install All In One WP Migration Plugin
Step3 : Import .wpress file Dashboard -> All In One WP Migration -> Import
Step4 : set permalink

And then check site working or not